# Print text up to an element with XPath - PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath, html-parsing

Hello i have an element `<td>` and i want to save/print the content only until secondo `<br`
Is possible ?

This is html:

```
<td>
    <span class="HTML_ELM">Coniugazione di: </span>
    <span class="style11">
        <span class="HTML_ELM">moneo</span>
    </span>, monĕs, monui, monitum, monēre<br> // **STOP HERE MY FRIENDS !**
    <span class="HTML_ELM"> coniugazione: : </span>2 - transitivo - attiva<br>
    <span class="HTML_ELM">   significato: </span>ammonire, <a href="Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=moneo&amp;tradinv=avvertire&amp;lang=IT_">avvertire</a>,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>(eng) = <a href="Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=moneo&amp;tradinv=warn&amp;lang=EN_">warn</a>,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=moneo&amp;tradinv=advise&amp;lang=EN_">advise</a>,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=moneo&amp;tradinv=presage&amp;lang=EN_">presage</a>,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>(esp) = <a href="Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=moneo&amp;tradinv=avisar&amp;lang=ES_">avisar</a>,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;<br>
 </td>
```

I tried to use `explode`:

```
 $query_paradigma = '//span[contains(@class, "style11")][1]/parent::td';        
 $contenuto_paradigma = $xpath->query($query_paradigma);
 $paradigma= explode("<br>",$contenuto_paradigma);
        
 print_r($paradigma[0]." <br>");
 print_r($paradigma[1]." <br>");
```

But i have this error: **explode() expects parameter 2 to be string**

I hope you can help me, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you run `query()`, this will give you a set of DOM elements and not the actual HTML of the content.

So `$contenuto_paradigma` will be a list of matching nodes, you only want the first match (you could loop over them if you wanted more).  Then export the HTML of this node (the `<td>` node) using `$dom->saveHTML()` (note that `$dom` is the name of your document, so change as needed).  Then you can extract the data from there...

```
$query_paradigma = '//span[contains(@class, "style11")][1]/parent::td';
$contenuto_paradigma = $xpath->query($query_paradigma);
$tdContent = $dom->saveHTML($contenuto_paradigma[0]);

$paradigma= explode("<br>",substr($tdContent, 4)););
```

(The `substr` just removes the `<td>` tag from the start).

Comment: I tried your code, adding before $dom_td= new DOMDocument(); (i changed name of variable $dom in $dom_td) but i have error:  Uncaught DOMException: Wrong Document Error

Comment: You need to use the same DOM that was used to create the DOMXPath object.